# How to create multiple VMs in multiple Subnets using terraform modules

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm new to terraform and trying to create a module for multiple vms and within multiple subnets within multiple regions.

I have 2 regions, in each region i have 3 subnets and within each subnet I'm creating 2 vms.

I'm able to create multiple subnets within the 2 regions using the module but I need help in creating multiple vms within these multiple subnets created. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Below is my code for the main.tf as well as terraform.tfvars

**terraform.tfvars**

```
  # subnets
    subnet = {
      "Subnet1" = {
        name                                            = "subnet1"
        address_prefixes                                = [""]
        enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies  = 
      },
      "Subnet2" = {
        name                                            = "subnet2"
        address_prefixes                                = [""]
        enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies  = 
      },
      "Subnet3" = {
        name                                            = "subnet3"
        address_prefixes                                = [""]
        enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies  = 
      },
    }
    

    # vms
    vm = {
      "vm1" = {
        name            = "vm1"
        size            = ""
        admin_username  = ""
        zone            = ""
        vtpm_enabled    = true

        nic = {
          name                = ""
          ip_name             = ""
          private_ip_address  = "" 
        }
      },
      "vm2" = {
        name            = "vm2"
        size            = ""
        admin_username  = ""
        zone            = ""
        vtpm_enabled    = true

        nic = {
          name                = ""
          ip_name             = ""
          private_ip_address  = ""
        }     
      },
```

**main.tf**

```
module "subnet" {
  source = "./../modules/subnet"
  depends_on = [module.vnet]
  for_each = var.region.subnet

  # Resource group
  network_rg_name  = var.region.network_rg_name    
  location            = var.region.location

  # Route table
  route_table_id = module.route_table.route_table_id

  # Network
  subnet  = each.value
  vnet    = var.region.vnet

}


module "vm" {
  source = "./../modules/vm"
  for_each    = var.region.vm
  
  # Resource group
  vm_rg_name  = var.region.vm_rg_name    
  location    = var.region.location

  # Subnets
  vm_subnet_id = module.subnet["Subnet1"].subnet_id
 
  # Virtual Machine
  vm        = each.value
  vm_shared = var.tfvars.vm_shared
  vm_pwd    = var.vm_pwd    
}
```

Comment: What's not working with your current solution?

Comment: @DanielMann how do i assign each subnet_id value to the vms? Currently I'm only doing it for Subnet1

Comment: The answer would be probably more complicated than you would like. I would suggest doing everything with one of each, then studying how you can achieve what you want. Hint: you cannot use different variables in `for_each` and expect to make a mapping work.

Answer (score 0):

This may work

In terraform.tfvars edit the vms, adding the name of you required subnet

##### terraform.tfvars

```
...
# vms
    vm = {
      "vm1" = {
        name            = "vm1"
        size            = ""
        admin_username  = ""
        zone            = ""
        subnet          = "subnet1"  ### require subnet
        vtpm_enabled    = true

        nic = {
          name                = ""
          ip_name             = ""
          private_ip_address  = "" 
        }
      },
      "vm2" = {
        name            = "vm2"
        size            = ""
        admin_username  = ""
        zone            = ""
        subnet          = "subnet2"  ### require subnet
        vtpm_enabled    = true

        nic = {
          name                = ""
          ip_name             = ""
          private_ip_address  = ""
        }     
      },
```

In your main.tf add a condition and a "locals"

##### main.tf

```
   locals {
          subnet1 = module.Subnet["Subnet1"].subnet_id
          subnet2 = module.Subnet["Subnet2"].subnet_id
          subnet3 = module.Subnet["Subnet3"].subnet_id
        }
    
    module "vm" {
          source = "./../modules/vm"
          for_each    = var.region.vm
          
          # Resource group
          vm_rg_name  = var.region.vm_rg_name    
          location    = var.region.location
        
          # Subnets
          vm_subnet_id = "${each.value.subnet}" == "subnet1" ? "${local.subnet1}" : "${each.value.subnet}" == "subnet2" ? "${local.subnet2}" : "${each.value.subnet}" == "subnet3" ? "${local.subnet3}" :""
         
          # Virtual Machine
          vm        = each.value
          vm_shared = var.tfvars.vm_shared
          vm_pwd    = var.vm_pwd    
        }
```

Hope this helps!